# Hamming distance calculation in the paper "unsupervised learning of visual representation by solving Jigsaw puzzle"

Tags: deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09246. Here they speak about calculating the hamming distance for the generated permutations. 
In algorithm 1, under the iteration part the calculation of Hamming is written as follows:

D <- Hamming(P,P')

where I believe P is the permutation selected and P' is its transpose.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain me this calculation.

Note: I know how to calculate the hamming distance between 2 strings, I am confused on the calculation between the matrices.

Comment: Relevant:   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98546/hamming-distance-approximates-cayley-distance-on-permutations-citation-wanted          https://rdrr.io/cran/CEGO/man/distancePermutationHamming.html